LME4 model producing strange p values
When modelling QPCR data using LME4 I am getting a result that tells me my treatment effect is insignificant. When I plot the data this looks wrong and if I use JMPpro the p value for Treatment is tiny, as expected.
I have this data:
Strain <- c("A", "B", "C")
Strain <- rep(Strain, each = 18)


Treatment <- c("Water", "dsRNA")
Treatment <- rep(Treatment, each=3, times=9)

Time <- c("24", "48", "72")
Time <- rep(Time, each=6, times=3)

Cohort <- c("1", "2", "3")
Cohort <- rep(Cohort, times = 18)

deltaCT <- c(-2.772848129, -2.382880211, -2.802474976, -2.545639038, -2.363836288, -2.280316353, -2.418494225, -2.333683968, -2.999289513, -0.828756332, -2.032594681, -1.340758324, -2.595740318,
-2.231285095, -2.265996933, -1.700395584, -1.744121552, -1.32080555, -0.910932541, -2.313327789, -2.346955299, -1.538050652, -0.690214157, -1.678500175, -2.221671104, -3.087368965, -3.176133156,
-1.53543663, -2.560225487, -2.625535011, -3.341409683, -3.042736053, -3.546187401, -0.139810562, -2.315425873, -2.392004967, -2.916553497, -2.504823685, -3.253599167, -2.005877495, -2.682225227,
-3.007395744, -3.070969582, -3.156041145,-3.030291557,-0.097309113, -2.800593376, -2.803215981, -2.930361748, -2.752057076, -1.931899071, -1.238015175, -1.467027664,-1.421812057)

mdat <- data.frame(Strain, Treatment, Time, Cohort, deltaCT)

mdat$Strain <- factor(mdat$Strain)
mdat$Treatment <- factor(mdat$Treatment)
mdat$Time <- factor(mdat$Time)
mdat$Cohort <- factor(mdat$Cohort)


Using lme4 to run a mixed model, calculating the significance of the three fixed effects with interactions (Strain, Treatment and Time) and one random effect (Cohort) on deltaCT. My code looks like this:
m1 <- lmer(deltaCT ~ Treatment * Strain * Time + (1|Cohort), data = mdat)

Anova(m1, test.statistic = 'F',  type =3)

My results show that the Treatment effect is not significant but Strain is and the interaction between Strain and time is too:
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
Treatment p = 0.59228
Strain p = 0.02364 *
Strain:Time p = 0.04189 *
If I plot the data I can see the treatment effect is clearly very strong and if I parse the same data with JMPpro, the p value for Treatment is <0.001. The Strain and Strain:Time interaction may very well have significant effects on deltaCT but the Treatment effect should be stronger.
What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

You didn't compute the type 3 anova correctly: you need to set the sum contrast for the three factors. Also -- are you certain you want the type 3 anova in the first place?

I think type 3 is necessary when looking at interactions. How would I set the sum contrast ?

Your experimental design is balanced: there are two treatments, three strains and three time points, with 3 observations for every (treatment, strain, time) combination. In this situation, type 2 and type 3 ANOVAs produce the same result. Instead here's what we get with your code:
car::Anova(m1, test.statistic = "F", type = 2)
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: deltaCT
#>                             F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
#> Treatment             29.5543  1     34 4.656e-06 ***
#> Strain                 0.8296  2     34  0.444877    
#> Time                   0.6083  2     34  0.550118    
#> Treatment:Strain       0.1545  2     34  0.857424    
#> Treatment:Time         2.4734  2     34  0.099341 .  
#> Strain:Time            4.4768  4     34  0.005163 ** 
#> Treatment:Strain:Time  0.7148  4     34  0.587654

car::Anova(m1, test.statistic = "F", type = 3)
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: deltaCT
#>                             F Df Df.res  Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept)           43.5907  1 26.205 5.1e-07 ***
#> Treatment              0.2923  1 34.000 0.59228    
#> Strain                 4.1894  2 34.000 0.02364 *  
#> Time                   2.4952  2 34.000 0.09747 .  
#> Treatment:Strain       0.1086  2 34.000 0.89737    
#> Treatment:Time         0.9618  2 34.000 0.39236    
#> Strain:Time            2.7870  4 34.000 0.04189 *  
#> Treatment:Strain:Time  0.7148  4 34.000 0.58765

We can compute type 3 ANOVA correctly if we first "center" the predictors. We center continuous variables by subtracting the mean: x.c = x - mean(x); we center categorical variables by using the sum contrast (aka deviation coding): contrasts(A) = contr.sum(nlevels(A)). The default in R is the treatment contrast (aka dummy coding); it compares factor levels to one level chosen as reference rather than to the mean of all the levels.
So a correct way to fit the model if we want to use type 3 ANOVA is:
m1.sum.contr <- lmer(
  deltaCT ~ Treatment * Strain * Time + (1 | Cohort),
  data = mdat,
  contrasts = list(
    Treatment = "contr.sum",
    Strain = "contr.sum",
    Time = "contr.sum"
  )
)

Now we get the same table for type 2 and type 3 ANOVAs, as expected.
Note also that we get the correct table with type 2 whether we center the predictors or not. This is one reason to prefer type 2 over type 3. See this great answer by @gung to learn more: How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA? I also like this blog post: Everything You Always Wanted to Know About ANOVA
(But Were Afraid to Ask). Though I would say that you should know all that about ANOVA before using it to analyze your data.
car::Anova(m1.sum.contr, test.statistic = "F", type = 2)
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: deltaCT
#>                             F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
#> Treatment             29.5543  1     34 4.656e-06 ***
#> Strain                 0.8296  2     34  0.444877    
#> Time                   0.6083  2     34  0.550118    
#> Treatment:Strain       0.1545  2     34  0.857424    
#> Treatment:Time         2.4734  2     34  0.099341 .  
#> Strain:Time            4.4768  4     34  0.005163 ** 
#> Treatment:Strain:Time  0.7148  4     34  0.587654

car::Anova(m1.sum.contr, test.statistic = "F", type = 3)
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: deltaCT
#>                             F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept)            0.0000  1  2.014  1.000000    
#> Treatment             29.5543  1 34.000 4.656e-06 ***
#> Strain                 0.8296  2 34.000  0.444877    
#> Time                   0.6083  2 34.000  0.550118    
#> Treatment:Strain       0.1545  2 34.000  0.857424    
#> Treatment:Time         2.4734  2 34.000  0.099341 .  
#> Strain:Time            4.4768  4 34.000  0.005163 ** 
#> Treatment:Strain:Time  0.7148  4 34.000  0.587654

PS: In R, one way to check the contrasts used in fitting a model is with the model.matrix function. For example, model.matrix(m1) reports "contr.treatment" for the three predictors while model.matrix(m1.sum.contr) reports "sum.contr".
PPS: In a comment the OP writes that "type 3 is necessary when looking at interactions". This is a misunderstanding. See this discussion by @EdM: How does type II vs type III ANOVA work when there are more than two categorical predictors? and references therein.

That's brilliant, I'll look into those.  Thanks very much
